# How to share data between 2 angularjs apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 angular applications that connects to the same backend.

1. account.myweb.com is used to login, register and manage account
2. app.myweb.com is the real app.

On successful login at account.myweb.com, user will get access token and user details and will be redirected to app.myweb.com. This access token is needed by app.myweb.com. How can i share the data between the 2 apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that we can trick local storage to allow cross domain using iframe and postmessage. Theres angular module for it. https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $cookies: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Alternatively, we use `angular-local-storage`. It works well. https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: I was trying to use angular-local-storage but html5 local storage can not share data with other domain.

Comment: hmmm, how about using a simple query string?
`http://app.myweb.com/?token=xxxxxxxxx`
Then as soon as angular reads the token, you can have it automatically remove it from the URL and put it into its own local storage.

Comment: definitely the query parameter with the token.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can share between sub domains. In your case you can share same token between your 2 apps. after successful login store token like below

```
$cookies.put('tokenName', 'tockenValue', { domain: '.myweb.com' });
```

then you can access this token both apps.

Note - if your app running using angular version below 1.3, you cannot set cookies to specific domain. therefore you have to use

```
 $document[0].cookie = "tokenName"+ "=" + "tockenValue"+ ";domain=.myweb.com";
```